# C# How to skip lines in Text file after text converted to array?

Tags: c#, token, skip

I have a program which processes a text log file and tokenizes the text files.

After tokenizing the text file, the program should be able to skip the first 5 lines of the new output which contains

"RipXP v.20081001

Launched Fri Dec  3 12:50:21 2010 Z

J:\syscrawl\registry\config\system

USBStor

ControlSet001\Enum\USBStor"

Can someone please advise on the codes?

The Codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace Testing
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Test\new.txt");

        String SplitBy = "----------------------------------------";

        String fullLog = tr.ReadToEnd();

        String[] sections = fullLog.Split(new string[] { SplitBy }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (String r in sections)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
            Console.WriteLine("============================================================");
        }
    }
  }
  }
```

An Sample of the output:

"RipXP v.20081001
Launched Fri Dec  3 12:50:21 2010 Z

J:\syscrawl\registry\config\system
USBStor
ControlSet001\Enum\USBStor

CdRom&Ven_SanDisk&Prod_Ultra_Backup&Rev_8.32 [Wed Dec  1 07:39:09 2010
  S/N: 2584820A2890B317&1 [Wed Dec  1 07:39:22 2010]
    FriendlyName  : SanDisk Ultra Backup USB Device

CdRom&Ven_WD&Prod_Virtual_CD_070A&Rev_1032 [Wed Dec  1 07:31:33 2010]
  S/N: 575836314331304639303339&1 [Fri Dec  3 05:41:48 2010]
    FriendlyName  : WD Virtual CD 070A USB Device

Disk&Ven_SanDisk&Prod_Ultra_Backup&Rev_8.32 [Wed Dec  1 07:39:09 2010]
  S/N: 2584820A2890B317&0 [Wed Dec  1 07:39:19 2010]
    FriendlyName  : SanDisk Ultra Backup USB Device
    ParentIdPrefix: 8&2f23e350&0

Disk&Ven_WD&Prod_My_Passport_070A&Rev_1032 [Wed Dec  1 07:31:33 2010]
  S/N: 575836314331304639303339&0 [Fri Dec  3 05:41:48 2010]
    FriendlyName  : WD My Passport 070A USB Device

Other&Ven_WD&Prod_SES_Device&Rev_1032 [Wed Dec  1 07:31:33 2010]
  S/N: 575836314331304639303339&2 [Fri Dec  3 05:41:48 2010]

============================================================

Restore Point Info
Description   : System Checkpoint
Type          : System Checkpoint
Creation Time : Mon Nov 29 16:51:52 2010

J:\syscrawl\Restore\RP1\snapshot_REGISTRY_MACHINE_SYSTEM

ControlSet001\Enum\USBStor not found.

============================================================"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was the Stream Reader which should start reading the various line position before using the split method. The codes: [C# How to skip number of lines while reading text file using Stream Reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418319/c-how-to-skip-number-of-lines-while-reading-text-file-using-stream-reader/4418362#4418362)

Answer (score 1):

ooooh i think u want to concat string from original

String.Replace is best solution here

```
string data = tr.ReadToEnd();
data.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ")
.Replace("----------------------------------------", "============================================================");
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

edit again

sorry, i really dont understand the question. but to skip first 5 lines

```
string lines = tr.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 5; i < lines.Length; i++) sb.AppendLine(lines[i]);
string sixthLineToEnd = sb.ToString();
```

hope it help

Comment: I suggest you read the question again as the program should skip the first 5 lines of the output...

Comment: Sorry about that, i have made an edit. this should be your solution

Comment: The program does not need to skip new lines but rather "RipXP v.20081001 Launched Fri Dec 3 12:50:21 2010 Z
J:\syscrawl\registry\config\system USBStor ControlSet001\Enum\USBStor
" which is outputed when the program is computed.